# Employee's salary of all month of specific year

Tags: sql-server, telerik-reporting

I have 2 table `[EmployeeInfo]` and `[EmployeeInfoHistory]`.  I am storing salary of the employee in these tables. I am able to get the salary of the employee against respective employee and stuff.

But I want to show employee's salary for every month as listed below.

My structure is for [EmployeeInfo]:

```
Create Table [EmployeeInfo]
(
    EmpID Int,
    Salary Int,
    EmployementStatus Varchar(50),
    HiringDate Date
);
```

My structure is for [EmployeeInfoHistory]:

```
Create Table [EmployeeInfoHistory]
(
    EmpID Int,
    NewSalary Int,
    UpdatedEmployementStatus Varchar(50),
    PromotionDate Date
);
```

Data for Info Table:

```
EmpID  Salary  Status   HiringDate
1      20000   Intern   2017-10-02
2      30000   Jr. DBA  2017-11-01
```

Data for InfoHistory Table:

```
EmpID  Salary  UpdatedStatus   PromotionDate
1      25000   Jr. DBA         2018-01-01
2      45000   Sr. DBA         2018-01-01
```

I want to list data in given format:

```
EmpID   Month     Salary  Status
1       October   20k     Intern
1       November  20k     Intern
1       December  20k     Intern
1       January   25k     Jr. DBA
2       November  30k     Jr. DBA
2       December  30k     Jr. DBA
2       January   45k     Sr. DBA
```

A guy was able to help me out and we came up with a query but I am now getting the months salaries from the day employee joined the organization. I want for a specific year let's say 2017.

Here is the query:

```
; WITH DS AS
(
    SELECT cast (Dateadd(year, -25, getdate()) AS date) as [Date]
        UNION all
    SELECT dateadd(Month, 1, [Date])
        FROM DS
        WHERE Date < getdate()
)
Select 
    EMP.EmpID, 
    DateName(month, DS.[Date]) as [Month], 
    isnull(HIS.NewSalary, EMP.Salary) as Salary, 
    ISNULL(HIS.UpdatedStatus, EMP.EmployementStatus) as [Status]
from 
    EmployeeInfo as EMP
        inner join DS 
            on EMP.HiringDate <= DS.[Date]  
        left join EmployeeInfoHistory as HIS
            on HIS.EmpId = EMP.EmpID and HIS.PromotionDate <= DS.[Date]  
option (MaxRecursion 10000)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put "where YEAR(DS.[Date]) = 2017" before "option(MaxRecursion 10000)"

Comment: @DenisRubashkin That was easy. :)
Thank you  <3

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell I agree with Denis, but here is my approach. It removes the need for recursion, using a tally table instean.

```
IF ((SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t')) IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #t
IF ((SELECT OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#calendar')) IS NOT NULL)
    DROP TABLE #calendar


SELECT TOP (25 *12) -- 25 years
       IDENTITY(INT,0,1) AS N
INTO  #T
FROM  master.sys.all_columns ac1
        CROSS JOIN master.sys.all_columns ac2

SELECT  N
      , [StartOfMonth] = DATEADD( MONTH, DATEDIFF( MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-n, 0)
      , [Month]        = DATENAME(MONTH, DATEADD( MONTH, DATEDIFF( MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-n, 0))
      , [Year]         = DATENAME(YEAR,  DATEADD( MONTH, DATEDIFF( MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-n, 0)) 
      , [EndOfMonth]   = DATEADD( SECOND, -1,  DATEADD( MONTH, DATEDIFF( MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-n+1, 0))
INTO    #Calendar
FROM #T

SELECT  e.EmpID, 
        c.StartOfMonth,
        c.Month, 
        ISNULL(h.NewSalary, e.Salary) as Salary, 
        ISNULL(h.UpdatedEmployementStatus, e.EmployementStatus) as [Status]
FROM    EmployeeInfo as e
        INNER JOIN #Calendar c 
                ON e.HiringDate <= c.EndOfMonth
        LEFT JOIN EmployeeInfoHistory as h
                ON h.EmpId = e.EmpID 
                AND h.PromotionDate <= c.EndOfMonth
WHERE   c.Year = 2017
ORDER BY e.empid, c.StartOfMonth
```